# How to get overscan working on RasPi 4?

Tags: pi-4, display, raspi-config, raspberry-pi-os-bullseye, raspberry-pi-desktop

This has been asked multiple times in multiple forums. Invariably the answer is editing `/boot/config.txt`. This doesn't solve the issue.

My RasPi's connected to a TV via HDMI0. The TV is one of those old "HD-ready" thingys, native resolution is 1280x720 but it can do full 1080p. I usually run it on 720, but the problem is present with both. I'd need to get overscan about 20 - 24 on the horizontal plane but it's not happening.

Here are my current settings:

```
# Disable compensation for displays with overscan
#disable_overscan=1

# uncomment the following to adjust overscan. Use positive numbers if console
# goes off screen, and negative if there is too much border
overscan_left=100
overscan_right=100
#overscan_top=16
#overscan_bottom=16
```

Current 100 is purposefully overdone to see if L/R overscan has *any* effect. It doesn't.

The problem's present in the current Raspberry Pi OS, whether or not it's running from SD card or an external SSD or USB stick. I've re-flashed it now four times over on different SD cards, current iteration is a fresh install on a USB stick.

For testing I installed Gentoo with [PINN](https://pinn.mjh.nz/), and had no issues, so that'd be an obvious workaround. However I'd like to stick to RasPi OS as I'm most at home with Debian-based OS.

The TV has no menu item to affect the overscan. What else can I try to fix this?

Answer (score 1):

The only way I could get this to work was to disable the "new" video driver, which apparently ignores all of these values.

Further down in config.txt, you have to comment out this line:

```
dtoverlay=vc4-kms-v3d
```

Doing this will reduce some functionality (acceleration? 4k?) but at least you can see the whole screen.

Also note the "disable_overscan=1" should be uncommented, or else it seems to add an **extra** 48 pixels around the border which is both unintuitive and poorly documented.

Comment: Thanks. In the meantime I bought another used TV (old "HD-ready" i.e. max 1080i - then again only 20 euros) which only shows the issue on max reso. I'll check when I get around to it :-)

Answer (score 1):

I was able to fix it using some information posted on [this github issue](https://github.com/raspberrypi/firmware/issues/1285) back in 2019. This also works with the Pi5; it's about the library not the hardware. This is now the default library in use with Raspberry Pi OS 12, aka Bookworm.

Commands have to be passed directly in to `vc4-kms-v3d` at boot to tweak the margins on the screen. There were a couple steps:

1. Get the name of the display you want to modify by clicking on `Raspberry Pi Menu > Preferences > Screen Configuration`

   - This is the menu in the upper left of the main desktop - assuming you can see it
   - The identifier of the display should show up in the "Screen Layout Editor" window
   - Take a note of this name, in my instance it was called `HDMI-A-1`
2. Open a new terminal in order to edit `cmdline.txt`

   - Run the command `sudo nano /boot/cmdline.txt`
3. Add the following text to the end of the single line contained in `cmdline.txt`

   - `video=HDMI-A-1:1920x1080@60,margin_left=40,margin_right=40,margin_top=32,margin_bottom=32`

     - **Note:** The name of the display is followed by the desired resolution, refresh rate and margin values
     - All of this information should be pasted directly to the end of the single line of text that is already in `cmdline.txt`
     - It appears to me that `cmdline.txt` is space delimited
     - Adjust the margin values as needed, adding to them to make the padding around the edge of the display larger
     - i.e. **bigger** margin number = **smaller** display in the TV
   - You'll need to reboot the system to see the changes go in to effect.

Took a little bit of digging in to `vc4-kms-v3d` to get a straight and effective answer that wasn't dependent upon some setting in the television itself.

Comment: Thank you @Shrout1, this worked with a Raspberry Pi 5, the latest Raspbian, and an Older Roku TV.

Comment: @DaveNelson I’m glad you got it working! I figured there was a way to fix it… The never ending joys of Linux :D

Comment: I tried this on my pi 3, but it isn't working for me. I'm using the composite video output. My cmdline.txt is listed below if anyone has ideas.

console=serial0,115200 console=tty1 root=PARTUUID=97d9e0e1-02 rootfstype=ext4 fsck.repair=yes rootwait quiet splash plymouth.ignore-serial-consolesvideo=Composite-1:720x480@60,margin_left=32,margin_right=32,margin_top=32,margin_bottom=32

Comment: @zjdrummond what OS do you have installed on your pi? Are you using the `vc4-kms-v3d` library for video?

Comment: Yes, and I'm on raspberry pi os bullseye.

Comment: @zjdrummond I used this fix on Bookworm as the video library has changed. The legacy instructions should work better for you - the `/boot/config.txt` file can have the `disable_overscan` option modified [as per this raspberry pi forum post](https://forums.raspberrypi.com/viewtopic.php?t=312217#:~:text=Set%20disable_overscan%20to%201%20to,value%20for%20disable_overscan%20is%200.) Hope this helps!